# Wordpress Custom Woocommerce category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have pages for every category in woocommerce. These are listed as follows:

```
http://example.com/parent-category/category-a
http://example.com/parent-category/category-b
http://example.com/parent-category/category-c
```

I want to customise the last link to be a custom-built page but still retain the link and not just doing redirects.

I currently use `WooCommerce Permalink Settings` plugin

Comment: Information about creating a specific custom category page can be found here https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Answer (score 0):

Create file `"some-single.php"` and after this create `"some-yourCategoryName"`. Now open `single.php` and and replace this `get_template_part('content','single');` by following code

with this:

```
   if(is_category('yourCategoryName')){
        get_template_part('content','yourCategoryName');
    }else{
        get_template_part('content','single.php');
    }
```

Will be fine.